# Three.js MeshPhongMaterial normalScale throwing error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've got a MeshPhongMaterial named 'material' like so:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/images/8k-earth-diffuse.jpg'),
        normalMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/images/8k-earth-normal.jpg'),
        normalScale: (0.1, 0.1),
        specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/images/8k-earth-spec.png'),
        specular: new THREE.Color('grey')
    });
```

Everything works and is applied, including the map and normalMap. The problem is, when I try to add a `normalScale` property, it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'uniform2fv' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

I've used `normalScale` before and with the right syntax, and it's been working until recently. Without `normalScale` everything is fine. I am using revision 77. My question is why is this happening and what causes this error? How can I use `normalScale` without three.js throwing the error? I've used Chrome DevTools to get the line where the error is thrown in three.js source:

```
if ( v.x === undefined ) gl.uniform2fv( this.addr, v );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting `normalScale` properly:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {

    normalMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/images/8k-earth-normal.jpg'),

    normalScale: new THREE.Vector3( 0.1, 0.1 );

) };
```

Alternatively, after the material is instantiated:

```
material.normalScale.set( 0.1, 0.1 );
```

three.js r.77